# Seeking Advice For Oracle Data-Intensive Application

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, web-applications, view, stored-functions

I'm endeavoring to develop an application that uses Oracle as the database back-end. The application will calculate several statistics from the various tables in the database. The front-end will most likely be a web application and this front-end will display various charts and calculated statistics. Now, I imagine that it would be more efficient to perform the calculations in the database rather than in the service layer because said calculations would need to be performed for every web request. That being the case, I'm not sure which mechanism to use. (e.g. stored procedure, function, view) To illustrate what I'm going for, suppose I want to keep statistics of student grades for many students. I would like to have a web interface that lets me view those statistics on student-by-student basis and also an all-inclusive basis. Some of the stats are dependent on aggregates (e.g. average, min, max) of all of the student grades and some stats are dependent only on an individual student. In this situation, every time a record is added or updated, the aggregates would have to be recalculated. So I am speculating that if I had a special table that held all of the calculated values I need and a trigger(s) to recalculate everything when a record is added/updated then all I would need to do from a web request point-of-view is have the service layer pull the desired values from this special table. I'm just not sure if this is the best way to go or not so I am asking the community for any input/advice. Note: Although I'm using Oracle, I'm open to using PostgreSQL or mySQL.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The scenario you are describing would be ideal for using materialized views. They can be designed to refresh automatically (and incrementally) every time the source data is updated by your application. The calculations would be built in to the view definition. No triggers required, and likely no stored procedures unless your calculations involve multiple steps. Check here: https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/materialized-views and here: https://medium.com/oracledevs/lightning-fast-sql-with-real-time-materialized-views-12-things-developers-will-love-about-oracle-54bcc9eac358 for more info.